Ubuntu 20+ doesn't connect to non-internet WIFI
I have some device, that acts as open wifi hotspot (of course with no internet access) to connect to it and to use via web interface. Unfortunately any UBUNTU version more than 18 (20.04, 22, 24) don't connect to it - "Activation of connection failed" error message arrives and nothing happened. I tried to save the network with custom IP settings, using wpa_supplicant, but didn't succeed.
Any other wifi connection works (open, secured, no matter, but with internet access, so looks like it's the problem)
THe only way to use the device is to load older OS (I use 18.04 on live-usb).


    Ubuntu 20 dmesg:
    [  204.914068] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  204.946317] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  204.947969] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  204.962735] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  204.964381] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  204.998854] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  205.000473] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  205.012058] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  205.013681] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  205.283160] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  205.285568] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  205.296491] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  205.298097] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  205.338695] wlp0s20f3: Trigger new scan to find an IBSS to join
[  205.492585] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp0s20f3: link becomes ready
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-67-generic #74~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 22 14:52:34 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux





    Ubuntu 24 dmesg:
    [58917.555033] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_change_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16
[58917.660067] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_change_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16
[58917.764871] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_change_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16
[58917.869779] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_change_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16
[58917.974712] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_change_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16
[58918.079550] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_change_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16
[58918.184316] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_change_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16
[58918.289046] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_change_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16
[58918.393253] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_change_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16
[58918.497720] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_change_iface: iface validation failed: err=-16
[58918.602320] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
emercom@RPI-Argon:~$ uname -a
Linux RPI-Argon 6.8.0-1007-raspi #7-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jun 24 10:21:12 UTC 2024 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux




    Ubuntu 18 (working)
    [  137.602528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[  137.771699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[  137.784641] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-84-generic #94~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 23:17:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



Is it any way to connect to this device with newer versions?
Thanks a lot in advance

Details matter, and you're vague with details. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the HWE kernel stack for example is using the same kernel as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the GA kernel stack; thus I'd expect identical results; OR if you weren't then you've got key detail that can be used to fix the issue. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, 20.04 LTS etc are available with 5 kernel stacks on live media (20.04 has 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15 for example) thus which did you try???  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS likewise has options (4.15, 4.18, 5.0, 5.3, 5.4) thus knowing what you actually used is useful detail at resolving your issue..

You've provided no specifics; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is available on live media (ie. different ISOs you can download) using 5 kernels as I mentioned in last comment; 22.04 is likewise available using 5 kernels (5.15, 5.19, 6.2, 6.5 & 6.8) etc... giving you 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13, 5.15, 5.19, 6.2, 6.5 & 6.8 just for two releases (6 ISOs each for 20.04 & 22.04)...    There is choice beyond just the release/version & specific/details do matter, as if we're not told exactly what you tried - we cannot respond.

I retried my test with 3 versions:

Ubuntu 18 live cd (Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-84-generic #94~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 23:17:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and it was the only working
Ubuntu 20 live cd (Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-67-generic #74~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 22 14:52:34 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
Ubuntu 24 Raspberry PI (Linux RPI-Argon 6.8.0-1007-raspi #7-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jun 24 10:21:12 UTC 2024 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux)
dmesg outputs will be soon


Your last edit shows it working on the GA kernel stack of 20.04; so have you tried 20.04 using the GA kernel stack??  The 20.04 GA kernel (5.4) was backported to 18.04 as the optional HWE kernel stack as per my first comment; so try it on 20.04... note I've assumed you mean 20.04 & not Ubuntu Core 20; ie. linux-generic | 5.4.0.193.191          | focal-security    | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x

Another thing was found. The same live disk works one one computer and fails with the known error on other. The difference is that on second computer Ubuntu 17 didn't recognize the wifi card and iwlwifi needed to be installed. It looks like the problem comes from the network driver
